# how to hide specific selected options in other select dropdown

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have two select drop downs with same options. The first drop down default selected option should be "Public Address" and second drop down default selected option should be "Add address".

I should allow to enter "Public Address / Worker Address" only once. So I need to hide "Public Address" option in second drop down on page load. And allow user to choose ""Public Address / Worker Address" option only once from either drop downs.

Here sharing Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/9G7BCyK37CNf6RWjU9Cz?p=preview

```
Please refer Plunker link
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Your thinking is wrong. You can not hide `<option>` tag across all browsers, it is not supported in some. You want a filter

Comment: I am good if its supports in modern browsers. It will be great help if you can share other possible options/solutions to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: For starters scale the demo down so it only includes the basics for the `<select>`'s ... as in [mcve]. All the other stuff is irrelevant to the problem

Comment: Updated  Plunker link which contains problem related code only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you rely on `Angular` to do this and forget about using `jQuery` directly as it's not necessary.

What you can do is have a main list of all the options and maintain two separate lists for the selects. When the selection changes you'll rebuild the lists. The example here isn't based on the code in your plunker but rather a PoC. What you should notice is the selected option in one select list cannot be an option in the other.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('controller', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.mainList = [{
      name: 'Public'
    }, {
      name: 'Private'
    }, {
      name: 'Protected'
    }, {
      name: 'Super'
    }, {
      name: 'Awesome'
    }, ];
    self.lists = [
      [],
      []
    ];
    self.selections = [self.mainList[0], self.mainList[1]];
    self.buildList = function(which, other) {
      self.lists[which] = [];
      self.mainList.forEach(function(e) {
        if (e.name !== self.selections[other].name) {
          self.lists[which].push(e);
        }
      });
    };
    self.buildLists = function() {
      self.buildList(0, 1);
      self.buildList(1, 0);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller as c" ng-init="c.buildLists()">
  <label>First</label>
  <select ng-model="c.selections[0]" ng-change="c.buildLists()" 
          ng-options="o.name for o in c.lists[0]">
  </select>
  <label>Second</label>
  <select ng-model="c.selections[1]" ng-change="c.buildLists()" 
          ng-options="o.name for o in c.lists[1]">
  </select>
</div>
```